# Fade in div on mouseover

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How do I fade in a div on a mouseover event on a button, after X seconds using Prototype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('myDiv').observe('mouseover',function() {
   new Effect.Fade('myDiv', {duration:300});
   }
)
```